# Precache / Preload directory

Tags: image, caching, load, onload, preload

Been looking around for ways to preload a directory of images, found this to be the best script provided here: http://perishablepress.com/3-ways-preload-images-css-javascript-ajax/
I like this best as it waits for current document to load before preloading, but I'd like to get this guy to load a directory of images instead of having to specify each file, and am pretty new to javascript, any help appreciated.

```
function preloader() {
if (document.images) {
    var img1 = new Image();
    var img2 = new Image();
    var img3 = new Image();

    img1.src = "http://domain.tld/path/to/image-001.gif";
    img2.src = "http://domain.tld/path/to/image-002.gif";
    img3.src = "http://domain.tld/path/to/image-003.gif";
    }
}
function addLoadEvent(func) {
    var oldonload = window.onload;
    if (typeof window.onload != 'function') {
    window.onload = func;
} else {
    window.onload = function() {
        if (oldonload) {
            oldonload();
        }
        func();
        }
    }
}
addLoadEvent(preloader);
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no general way to accomplish this. You need some way to retrieve the contents of a directory from the server, and there is no guarantee that your web server will provide a listing. In general, most web servers do not allow a client to list the contents of a server side directory.

If you control the Web Server, you can configure it so that a directory listing is shown, for example, when you ask for "http://domain.tld/path/to/". But even then, the format of the returned response will likely be different, depending on the web server.

However, if you are able to get a listing of the images in a given directory from the server, you will still need to use some technique such as AJAX, or a hidden IFRAME, to load those image names. Then you could use JavaScript to iterate over the file names, construct the URL, and make an Image object for each.